# Allowing users to set variables that determine behavior of commands run on terminal

Tags: xterm

I want users to be able to set a variable they can use to define the level of verbosity when they run commands in the command line, when they initiate a new terminal session.

One way to set a variable is to include it in `~/.bashrc`.  In its simplest form, a command like `echo export MYVAR=value >> ~/.bashrc` already makes the variable available for future interactive shells.

Is this the best way to give additional control of commands to users?
The problem is that I would like for users to change the value directly from the terminal rather than having to change the value by modifying their `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:**

Include (in simplest form) a line having e.g.
`source $HOME/.majvar.sh` in `.bashrc`

... then manipulate the content of `/home/$USER/.majvar.sh` by any feasible means; e.g. create a python program of your own, if `echo >.majvar.sh "export MYVAR=value"` isn't "good enough".

clues:
https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=python+name+of+logged+in+user
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file

**Alternatively:**
Make `.majvar` contain only the VALUE
and have `.bashrc` contain something similar to

```
if [ -r .majvar ] ;then
  set MYVAR="$( cat .majvar )"
  export MYVAR  # see man bash, search for 'export'
fi
```